# How to share security cookie across multiple applications using ASP.NET Identity 2.0?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Is it possible to have a single security database and use a WebAPI to log the user in / create the cookie.

Then have multiple MVC applications use that cookie. For example I could have User1 with roles: ApplicationA, and ApplicationB, and when the user went to ApplicationA they would have to log in using the WebAPI, it would then allow them access to the controllers I had set to authorize on role ApplicationA.

Then, if from ApplicationA, they navigated to ApplicationB, instead of making them sign in again, it used the same cookie and  knew they were authorized, and just had to check the role to make sure they had access to controllers I had set to authorize on role ApplicationB.

If they navigated to ApplicationC it would recognize them as an authorized user, but I could control access to the controllers in that application with role ApplicationC, which User1 did not have, so it would redirect them to a log in screen and/or tell them their username doesn't have access.

I have multiple applications using the same security database, but as it stands if you navigate from one to the other it makes you sign in again, which I want to avoid.

Before I went into more detail on what I have going on right now with code examples, I wanted to make sure how I wanted this to work was possible and if I going about it the right way and using the right approach.

Thank you for feedback.